# mutate cells of a range of columns if the column name is in another column

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset where I would like to change a cell value in a range of columns, if the column name is in another column.

I know I can loop through cells, and use ifelse, but this becomes very slow very soon, it seems. I got as far as using mutate() and across() but cannot work out how to make a logical with the column name.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest a vectorized approach, or point me to a similar question (which I was unable to find!), using tidyverse if possible.

Example of a dataset and the nested for loops:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,7,8)
c <- c(9,10,11,12)
d <- c("a","b","c","none")
test <- data.frame(a,c,b,d)

for(column in 1:3){
    for(row in 1:nrow(test)){
        test[row,column] <- ifelse(names(test)[column] == test$d[row], -99, test[row, column])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jasja, if my answer solved your question and was correct, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question in using current_col() which gives the name of the current column in an across()function, using ifelse().

```
test %>% mutate(across(c(a, b, c), ~ifelse(cur_column() == d, -99, .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for every column of interest as well as any reference column in your dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  mutate(a = case_when(
    d == names(test)[1] ~ -99,
    T ~ a
  ))
```

You could then add a new mutate, or include it in the same mutate, per "target" column (i.e.)

```
test %>% 
  mutate(a = case_when(
    d == names(test)[1] ~ -99,
    T ~ a
  )) %>% 
  mutate(b = case_when(
    d == names(test)[2] ~ -99,
    T ~ b
  ))
```

If you have multiple source columns (i.e. Columns like `d`, then you would need to add new rows to your mutates that account for that column, however since your test does not include that I won't get into it unless required.

Comment: Looking at this again, you could also develop this into a function to throw this into a map or apply function.

Comment: Thank you Hansel, that solves part of the puzzle.
Ideally, I would do this using an across(), asI have ~20 columns. But I cannot work out how to then use a 'generic' names() for each column. names(test)[.] did not work.

Comment: Hansel, with your suggestion helping me on the way I found a way to do this over many columns, using across() and current_col(). see below!